# Angularjs/Karma: Uncaught ReferenceError: inject is not defined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I got this service

```
angular.module('common.utils', [])

.service('Timer', function () {
    function Timer() {
        var start = new Date();
        return function () {
           return (new Date()).getTime() - start.getTime();
        };
    }
    return Timer;
});
```

And i'm trying to write a simple test for it:

```
describe('common.utils', function() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('common.utils');
    });

    it('has a timer service', inject(function(Timer) {
        expect(Timer).not.toBeNull();
    }));

});
```

And I keep getting `ReferenceError: inject is not defined`.

I included `angular.js`, `angular-mocks.js` and all the app files (`module` is working... ). I don't understand what the problem is...

Comment: double check if angular-mocks is included! if it is then inject function should be available in window object.

Comment: It does, i run in debug just to make sure - See [here](https://imgur.com/RW2XvG6)

Comment: Could you share your karma conf file?

Comment: It's the standard file produced by `karma init`. The files are specified by a gulp task anyway... I'm having trouble figuring out where `inject` is available. Seems like I can only use it in `beforeEach`.

Comment: check if you have included angular.mock.js in files field of karma conf object. you can be able to use inject function in 'it' (it is obvious, since it is available in window), I have done it in my test.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It turns out the issue was in the loading order of the files. You have to load `jasmine` before you load `angular-mocks`.

The following loading order will be throwing the error as mentioned in the question:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="/spec/test.js"></script>
```

> ReferenceError: inject is not defined

In several jasmine examples there is an additional comment included in the code:

```
<!-- include source files here... -->
```

The comment helps us to remind to load things in the right order.

```
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="/spec/test.js"></script>
```